# fields are $K(\pi,1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I want to prove that fields are (étale) $K(\pi,1)$.

One possibility would be to apply "If $Y \to X$ is a connected pro-étale Galois cover such that $Y$ is $K(\pi,1)$, then so is $X$." to $\mathrm{Spec}{K^{sep}} \to \mathrm{Spec}{K}$.

Are there other proofs?

Comment: Have you looked in Artin-Mazur's Étale homotopy theory book?

Comment: Yes, and I didn't find anything about this.